# can't log in to my off-line drupal site

Tags: users, navigation

I deleted the navigation-log-in pane.

I logged out, and when needed to log back in, wrote: "mysite/user" and the message I keep getting is as follows:

"
Not Found

The requested URL /pancher/user/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
"

Answer (score 1):

I've had some cases where clean url-s aren't working in offline mode. You should be able to log in using '?q=user' instead.